# Uploading files with two different keys in Asp.net Core Web API and Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have a Table (Course),two columns of CourseTable(ImageName and FileName) should have Course Image and course File, I can post file successfully, but image returns null always. My question is, how can I post two files, with two different keys ? Also if I want to send more than one file for CourseFile, how can I do that?

```
 public class FIleUploadAPI
    {
        public IFormFile FileName { get; set; }
        public IFormFile ImageName { get; set; }
        public string courseDto { get; set; }

    }

  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ApiResult<CourseResultDtoForPublic>> Create([FromForm] FIleUploadAPI objfile, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        await UploadFile(objfile);
        CourseDto courseDtoDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CourseDto>(objfile.courseDto);
        courseDtoDeserialize.FileName = objfile.FileName.ToString();
        courseDtoDeserialize.ImageName = objfile.ImageName.ToString();
        var model = courseDtoDeserialize.ToEntity(mapper);

        await courseRepository.AddAsync(model, courseDtoDeserialize.MajorId, cancellationToken);

        var dto = await courseRepository.TableAsNoTracking.ProjectTo<CourseResultDtoForPublic>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == model.Id, cancellationToken);
        return dto;



    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/Course/UploadFile")]
    //[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
    //[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
    public async Task<string> UploadFile([FromForm]FIleUploadAPI objfile)
    {
        if (objfile.FileName.Length > 0)
            
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\");
                }
                using (FileStream filestream = System.IO.File.Create(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\" + objfile.FileName.FileName))
                {
                    objfile.FileName.CopyTo(filestream);
                    filestream.Flush();
                    return "\\uploads\\" + objfile.FileName.FileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 return ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        if (objfile.ImageName.Length > 0)

        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads/CourseImages\\"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads/CourseImages\\");
                }
                using (FileStream filestream = System.IO.File.Create(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads/CourseImages\\" + objfile.ImageName.FileName))
                {
                    objfile.ImageName.CopyTo(filestream);
                    filestream.Flush();
                    return "\\uploads/CourseImages\\" + objfile.ImageName.FileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        
        else
        {
            return "Unsuccessful";
        }
        


    }
```

[image]

Comment: `I can post file successfully, but image returns null alway` Do you mean that the posted formdata from postman are not bound to your action parameter `FIleUploadAPI objfile` as expected?

Comment: CourseDto and FileName Parameters are bound correct from postman,but ImageName  return null value to my action parameter,although it has value on postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public IFormFile ImageName { get; set; }

> `CourseDto` and `FileName` Parameters are bound correct from postman,but ImageName return null value to my action parameter

Please note that model binding looks for matches to property_name (or parameter_name) from the value(s) in the request, in your screenshot we can find you specify the key with `ImagName` as below, not `ImageName`, which cause it can not bind the value to property well.

[image]

Please try to change it to `ImageName` in postman, then it should work as expected.

For more information about how model binding works, please check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: yes ,The problem was I had written imagename wrong, it was a flub! thanks for Replying.